# how can I read and translate incoming Notification from NotificationCenter?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I am trying to read Notification and do logic on it. my goal is reading incomig Notification from NotificationCenter, and if Notification says app is in background then print "app is in backgound". actually the right question is, how can I read and translate incoming Notification from NotificationCenter?

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("Hello, world!")
            .onReceive(NotificationCenter.default.publisher(for: UIApplication.willResignActiveNotification)) { Notification in
                if Notification == ? {
                    print("app is in backgound")
                }
    }
}
```

Comment: Just use `UIApplication.didEnterBackgroundNotification` and you don't need any condition - once received callback your app is in background.

Comment: I was using like that, but I thought How I could read Notification?

Comment: what do you meant by "read notification", on which notification you subscribed that, and only that, notification will come in callback. So, what to read?

Comment: I can tell you right now, if you subscribe to `willResignActiveNotification` then when it arrives you will absolutely not be in the background.

Comment: NotificationCenter is publishing something in up code right? if that is so, then it would publish a Notification. I am talking about reading this Notification.

Answer (score 0):

The notification has properties, including its `name` which identifies the "message" it is communicating to you.

For example, if you subscribe to

```
UIApplication.willResignActiveNotification
```

then the `name` will be

```
UIApplication.willResignActiveNotification
```

Comment: can you see my update code? is it right like that?

Comment: Did you try it? — But as I told you, I can guarantee that if the notification is `UIApplication.willResignActiveNotification`, you are _not_ in the background, so it is pretty silly to print that you _are_ in the background.

Comment: so i would not do silly things more. thanks